# Sort SortedList based on value C#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, sortedlist

I have a sorted list

```
private SortedList _slSorted = new SortedList();
```

`_slSorted` has value `Field` which is of type class  (actually 2 classes alternately dumped into them) having all the properties in them.

For example:

> `key:0 value:class1 object(having properties property 1 , property 2)`
>
> `key:1 value:class2 object(having properties property 3 , property 4)`
>
> `key:2 value:class1 object(having properties property 1 , property 2)`
>
> and so on..

I need to sort the `sortedList` based on either property 1 or property 3.

something like collect all the property values and sort them and rearrange

How can I do that?

Comment: `SortedList` uses key/value pairs. The list is sorted by key, not by value. Are you saying that you want to sort the values? Show us some code that illustrates how you populate the collection.

Comment: @JimMischel:yes by default the list will be sorted by key..but i want to sort them by values.thanks for your help..i managed to move all the values out and rearranged them and i could sort. i will post my working code soon as i dont have it right now with me.thanks again

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Sorted List by Value with Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649481/c-sharp-sorted-list-by-value-with-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new list that is sorted, by writing a class that implements `IComparer<object>`, and passing that to the LINQ `OrderBy` method. Like this:

```
SortedList theList = new SortedList();
// I assume you populate it here
// Then, to sort:
var sortedByValue = theList.Cast<object>().OrderBy(a => a, new ListComparer()).ToList();
```

That will sort the items and create a new `List<object>` called `sortedByValue`. The `ListComparer` is shown below.

Whereas this answers your question, I doubt that it's what you really want. But I don't know enough about your application, how you're using the `SortedList`, and what you want to do with the result above to give any kind of suggestion for doing it differently. I strongly suspect that you need to re-think your design, because what you're doing here is rather unusual.

Here's the `ListComparer`.

```
public class ListComparer: IComparer<object>
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (x == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (y == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (x is Class1)
        {
            if (y is Class1)
            {
                return (x as Class1).Prop1.CompareTo((y as Class1).Prop1);
            }
            // Assume that all Class1 sort before Class2
            return 1;
        }
        if (x is Class2)
        {
            if (y is Class2)
            {
                return (x as Class2).Prop3.CompareTo((y as Class2).Prop3);
            }
            if (y is Class1)
            {
                // Class1 sorts before Class2
                return -1;
            }
            // y is not Class1 or Class2. So sort it last.
            return 1;
        }
        // x is neither Class1 nor Class2 
        if ((y is Class1) || (y is Class2))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        // Don't know how to compare anything but Class1 and Class2
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @jimMischell-thanks for the detailed answer...i had solved this but using different mechanism..now replacing it with your code:)+1