# C# Sorted List by Value with Object

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I'm trying to create an "ordered" cache of objects in C#, where the order is determined by how many times that has been accessed.

I've looked into Dictionary, SortedList and SortedDictionary which were very close but don't quite have what I'm looking for.

I'd like to have a list which contains all the previously cached items, those items can have a `getHits()` method to determine what order the cached items should be in.

I can then access that cache by name and increase how many times an item has been viewed.

Simplified example (in **Pseudo C#**):

```
class Result {
  public int Hits = 0;
  public string Name = "";

  public void IncreaseHits() {
    this.hits++;
  }

  public Result(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Program {
  public MagicSortableType<string, Result> MyCache; //what structure to use?


  public main() {
    MyCache.Add(new Result("My result 1"));
    MyCache.Add(new Result("My result 2"));
    MyCache.Add(new Result("My result 3"));

    MyCache['My result 2'].IncreaseHits();
    MyCache['My result 2'].IncreaseHits();
    MyCache['My result 3'].IncreaseHits();

    MyCache.SortDesc(); //what is the real C# equivalent?

    foreach(Result result in MyCache) {
      Console.Write(result.Name + " - hits " + result.Hits);
    }
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
My result 2 - hits 2
My result 3 - hits 1
My result 1 - hits 0
```

Comment: In what way do the solutions you've tried not meet your requirements?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Can you explain?

Comment: What is `MyCache.SortDesc()` ? and how come you are adding in `SortedDictionary` without the key `MyCache.Add(new Result("My result 1"));` ?

Comment: The example I've outlined above isn't in real C#, it's what i'd "like" to be able to do, to help explain my question. I've added additional detail.

Comment: what kind of cache are you trying to create LRU/MRU some other version ?

Comment: MRU (so the results accessed the most) are at the top of the list.

Comment: What if multiple objects are equally popular?

Comment: it not MRU, since this consider the hit times, so if you have entry that have a lot of hits but didn't hit in this time interval the MRU with least hit will be remove from the cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I needed something like this, I created what I called an `MruDictionary`. It consisted of a `LinkedList<T>`, and a `Dictionary<string, LinkedListNode<T>>` (where `T` is the type of object, and the object key was type `string`).

Access is through the dictionary. When an item is accessed, it is moved to the head of the list. When an item is added, it's added to the head of the list. If the list size grows beyond the set maximum, the last node in the list is removed.

This worked very well. The items weren't kept in order by number of times used, but rather in strict MRU order. This *typically* kept the most often used items in the cache, but if there was a long period in which a popular item wasn't used, it would get flushed. For my purposes this worked very well.

I wrote an article about it. Full source with description is available at http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=626.

It should be easy enough to add the hit count if you really need it.

Comment: This sounds like a very strong solution and in effect is exactly what I'm trying to build. Will have a look through the article!

Comment: I actually implemented a combination of the suggestions but this is very close to what I put together.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon your pseudo code, this seems to be working:

```
var MyCache = new Dictionary<string, Result>
{
    {"My result 1", new Result("My result 1")},
    {"My result 2", new Result("My result 2")},
    {"My result 3", new Result("My result 3")},
    {"My result 4", new Result("My result 4")}
};

MyCache["My result 2"].IncreaseHits();
MyCache["My result 2"].IncreaseHits();
MyCache["My result 3"].IncreaseHits();

foreach (var result in MyCache.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Hits))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Value.Name + " - hits " + result.Value.Hits);
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to maintain the cache (for up to hours), would I just need to completely replace the "MyCache" with the output of your LINQ query?

Comment: You certainly can replace your `MyCache` with -> the ordered one (if you need I'd edit and include), however I do get an uneasy feeling about the solution.

Comment: Ideally I'd like a sort in place solution

Comment: Well here you certainly have sort in place, you can even replace MyCache with the sorted one.

Comment: Or by sort in place you mean, every time you increment the Hits your `Result` would re-arrange it's position and "sort itself" ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need something like:

```
SortedDictionary<string,int> MyCache = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
string strKey = "NewResult";
if (MyCache.ContainsKey(strKey))
{
    MyCache[strKey] = MyCache[strKey] + 1;
}
else
{
    MyCache.Add(strKey, 1);
}
```

But `SortedDictionary` is sorted on the key

[SortedDictionary - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)

> Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are sorted on the key.

You can extract the dictionary to `List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>` and then sort them based on teh value like:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> list = MyCache.ToList();
foreach (var item in list.OrderByDescending(r=> r.Value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key+ " - hits " + item.Value);
}
```

So you can have:

```
class Program
{
    public static SortedDictionary<string, int> MyCache = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        AddToDictionary("Result1");
        AddToDictionary("Result1");
        AddToDictionary("Result2");
        AddToDictionary("Result2");
        AddToDictionary("Result2");
        AddToDictionary("Result3");

        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> list = MyCache.ToList();
        foreach (var item in list.OrderByDescending(r=> r.Value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key+ " - hits " + item.Value);
        } 


    }
    public static void AddToDictionary(string strKey)
    {
        if (MyCache.ContainsKey(strKey))
        {
            MyCache[strKey] = MyCache[strKey] + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            MyCache.Add(strKey, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the output would be:

```
Result2 - hits 3
Result1 - hits 2
Result3 - hits 1
```

Comment: But then I've completely lost access to the Result objects, I guess I could create a hashmap with the same keys.

Comment: @PezCuckow, you can have a `List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>`, you can access the item based on the key and sort them based on the value.

Comment: If it is a List<T>, accessing item based on key wont be easy. You have to loop. Sorry state.

Answer (score 1):

Wonder if you are after something like this.

You could store two sets of relationships; all the objects, by key to make retrieval fast, and all of the objects by `Hits` to store the ordering. This has the added advantage of speeding up access - you can get the `Result`, the `Hits`, and therefore it's current and next index quite quickly.

When Getting a result, we lock the access to ensure we change it's order atomically, then return the object. We also cheat when writing out the number of hits; we know what the most popular is and then we can just walk backwards through that collection - could really even extract the keys to a `List<Int32>`, sort it, then iterate through that.

```
public class PopularityContest{

    private Dictionary<int, List<Result>> PopularityContainer { get; set; }

    private Dictionary<String, Result> ResultContainer { get; set; }

    private int MaxPopularity = 0;

    public PopularityContest(){
        PopularityContainer = new Dictionary<int, List<Result>>();
        ResultContainer = new Dictionary<String, Result>();
    }

    private Object _SyncLock = new Object();

    public Result GetResult(string resultKey)
    {

      Result result = ResultContainer[resultKey];

      lock(_SyncLock)
      {

        int currentHits = result.Hits;

        if(PopularityContainer.ContainsKey(currentHits) && PopularityContainer[currentHits].Contains(result))
        {
           PopularityContainer[currentHits].Remove(result);
        }

        if(!PopularityContainer.ContainsKey(currentHits + 1))
        {
          PopularityContainer.Add(currentHits + 1, new List<Result>());
        }

        PopularityContainer[currentHits + 1].Add(Result);

        if((currentHits + 1) > MaxPopularity) { MaxPopularity = currentHits + 1;}

      }

      return result;

    }


    public void WritePopularity()
    {

      //Here could also extract the keys to a List<Int32>, sort it, and walk that.
      //Note, as this is a read operation, dependent upon ordering, you would also consider locking here.

      for(int i = MaxPopularity; i >= 0; i--)
      {
         if(PopularityContainer.Contains(i) && PopularityContainer[i].Count > 0)
         {
            //NB the order of items at key[i] is the order in which they achieved their popularity
            foreach(Result result in PopularityContainer[i])
            {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} has had {1} hits", result.ToString(), i));
            }
         }

      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Cache below exposes a simple Add/Get interface for adding and retrieving items from the cache, which could obviously be improved upon.  It implements IEnumerable, which enumerates through the cache with the required behaviour.  There are obviously threading issues here that would need to be addressed.

```
public class Cache<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
    //Dictionary to hold the values of the cache
    private Dictionary<string, T> m_cacheStore = new Dictionary<string, T>();

    //Dictionary to hold the number of times each key has been accessed
    private Dictionary<string, int> m_cacheAccessCount = new Dictionary<string, int>(); 

    public T Get(string cacheKey)
    {
        if (m_cacheStore.ContainsKey(cacheKey))
        {
            //Increment access counter
            if (!m_cacheAccessCount.ContainsKey(cacheKey))
                m_cacheAccessCount.Add(cacheKey, 0);
            m_cacheAccessCount[cacheKey] = m_cacheAccessCount[cacheKey] + 1;

            return m_cacheStore[cacheKey];
        }
        throw new KeyNotFoundException(cacheKey);
    }

    public int GetHits(string cacheKey)
    {
        return m_cacheAccessCount.ContainsKey(cacheKey) ? m_cacheAccessCount[cacheKey] : 0;
    }

    public void Add(string cacheKey, T cacheValue)
    {
        if(m_cacheStore.ContainsKey(cacheKey))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("An element with the key {0} already exists in the cache", cacheKey));
        m_cacheStore.Add(cacheKey, cacheValue);
    }

    #region Implementation of IEnumerable

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var source in m_cacheAccessCount.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value))
        {
            yield return m_cacheStore[source.Key];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this implementation doesn't require an explicit "Increase Hits" call, but increments automatically when accessing the required cache item. If you wish to explicitly increment the counter from the consumer of the class then an appropriate method could be added to the public interface.

Answer (score 0):

The "Proper" way to do this is to implement IComparable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) Interface in your MyCache Class.

This will expose a method called CompareTo which you will have to write in your code.

You would just create that method and put some logic in there that says if this object is greater, less than or equal to the object passed in.

Then you use it in your client code by saying `int result = MyCache1.ComparTo(MyCache2);`

The result will be -1 0 or 1 based on if its greater than less than or equal too.

Comment: I've already put together a IComparable for the result class, what structure can I store those results in to allow me to `Sort()` them?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var MyCache = new SortedDictionary<string, int?>();
MyCache['My result 2'] = (MyCache['My result 2'] ?? 0) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this.

```
public class Result {
  public int Hits = 0;
  public string Name = "";

  public void IncreaseHits() {
    this.hits++;
  }

  public Result(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Program {
   public Dictionary<string, Result> MyCache; //what structure to use?


   public main() {
    MyCache.Add("My result 1", new Result("My result 1"));
    MyCache.Add("My result 2", new Result("My result 2"));
    MyCache.Add("My result 3", new Result("My result 3"));

    MyCache["My result 2"].IncreaseHits();
    MyCache["My result 2"].IncreaseHits();
    MyCache["My result 3"].IncreaseHits();

   foreach(Result result in MyCache.Values.OrderByDesc(x => x.Hits)) {
      Console.Write(result.Name + " - hits " + result.Hits);
   }
  }
}
```

Alternatively

```
public class MyCacheClass {

   private Dictionary<string,Result> cache = new Dictionary<string, Result>();

   public void IncreaseHits(string name) {
      Result cached;
      if (!cache.TryGetValue(name, out cached)) {
        cached = cache.Add(new Result(name));
      }
      cached.IncreaseHits();
   }

   public string Add(string name) {
      // Need to block duplicates....
      cache.Add(name, new Result(name));
   }

   public IEnumerable<Result> SortDesc {
      get { return cache.Values.OrderByDesc(x => x.Hits); }
   }
}


class Program {
   MyCacheClass MyCache = new MyCacheClass();

   MyCache.Add("result1");
   MyCache.IncreaseHits("My result 2");
   MyCache.IncreaseHits("My result 2");
   MyCache.IncreaseHits("My result 3");

   foreach(Result result in MyCache.SorDesc) {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - hits {1}",result.Name,result.Hits);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but instead of having to call a foreach, would like to be able to just Sort() the structure for later

Comment: @Pez `var forLater = MyCache.Values.OrderByDesc(x=>x.Hits).ToList()`

Answer (score -2):

Why not to use classic List and sort it, using sort method and write your own compare delagate ?

```
MyCache.Sort(delegate(Result a, Result b)
   {
      if (a.hits > b.hits) return -1;
      if (a.hits < b.hits) return 1;
      return 0;
   });
```

If you need access by key, you can have 2 structures. One for fast access, second holding sorted data.

```
Dictionary<String, Result> accessMap;
List<Result> MyCache;
accessMap["Object 1"] = obj1;
MyCache.add(obj1);

accessMap[Object 1].Increase();

//sort MyCache    

foreach(Result result in MyCache) {
  Console.Write(result.Name + " - hits " + result.Hits);
}
```

Comment: Because I can't access a classic list by key.

Comment: You can have List for sorting and Dictionary for accesing objects. Dictionary will not be sorted, but its OK, since you just use it for accesing. List will be sorted for print (other operations).